# Parallel transport along a cardioid

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, vector-analysis

I want to calculate an explicit example of a vector parallel transported along a cardioid to see what happens. Maybe someone could help me with that since no author of any book or pdf on the topic is capable of showing a single numerical example.

So we need a vector field on a manifold (which is the cardioid itself) $X=\frac{dx^{i}}{dt}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{i}}$ and a curve $x^{i}=x^{i}(t)$. My problem is, I'm not sure how to make up a curve + vector field on a manifold. Let's take the parametrization of the cardioid in Cartesian coordinates as

$x(t)=a(1+2\cos t + \cos 2t)$

$y(t)=a(2\sin t + \sin 2t)$

(I think this could be written in polar coordinates which would make more sense, but I'm not sure what happens there)

So I think this should be the curve on which the vector is transported. Now I'm not sure how to make up the vector field. For the vector field I also need a function $f$, but what function? A vector function? For example could I just take $f=r(\phi, \rho)= (\rho \cos \phi, \rho \sin \phi)$ (polar coordinates) and then $X=\frac{dx^{i}}{dt}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{i}}= \frac{dx(t)}{dt}\frac{\partial r(\phi, \rho)}{\partial \phi}+\frac{dy(t)}{dt}\frac{\partial r(\phi,\rho)}{\partial \rho}$ ? I think this looks right since the $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{i}}$ span the tangent space. Now how exactly does the condition for parallel transport in coordinates for this looks like? 
The general formula is

$\frac{\partial X^{\mu}}{dt}+ \Gamma^{\mu}_{v\lambda} \frac{\partial x^{v}(c(t))}{dt}X^{\lambda}=0$

(I know how to calculate the Levi-Civita connection with the metric,but I'm not sure about the rest)

Comment: I only learned parallel transport in general relativity course... but isn't the Christoffel symbols always 0 in R^2 since it is flat?

Comment: The parameters life in $R^{2}$ it is a map from $R^{2}$ into the manifold, the Christoffel symbols for polar coordinates are not vanishing. Sry if that was unclear.

Comment: Do you want to parallel-transport a vector tangent to the cardioid using the Levi-Civita connection of the induced metric there, or a vector tangent to $\mathbb{R}^2$ at a point on the cardioid along the cardioid, using the Levi-Civita connection of $\mathbb{R}^2$, which as Spark points out is flat? In either case the problem is more-or-less trivial; a standard example nonflat example is parallel transport along an arc on a sphere.

Comment: Sorry, I was confused. But if you choose Cartesian coordinate, doesn't Christoffel symbols all vanish?

Comment: @ Travis: The Christoffel symbols don't vanish in polar coordinates. I want to use a general vector and not the tangent to the cardioid. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CylindricalCoordinates.html

Comment: I deleted the parts with the sub-manifold and $R^2$. I should have written the whole mathematical details for a manifold and so on, but it's not important.I think everyone knows what I mean, I hope.

Comment: And Christoffel symbols are not tensors, so they could change from one coordinate system to another, which is exactly what they do when you transform from Cartesian to polar coordinates.

Comment: Can you please answer Travis's question carefully? If the manifold you care about is $R^2$ with the usual metric, and the cardiod is the curve along which you wish to transport some vector, then the transported vector at any point of the cardiod will be the same as the vector you started with (except with its basepoint changed, of course). If your manifold is the cardiod itself, and the curve along which you're transporting is also the cardiod, then the only vectors "allowed" are those tangent to the cardiod, which "parallel translate" by staying the same length and orientation at all points.

Comment: @John Hhm, ok I think the cardioid itself should be the manifold. But why are only tangent vectors to the cardioid allowed? And what happens at the singularity?

Comment: @user117640 If the manifold is the cardioid itself, then we're in the setting of intrinsic geometry on the cardioid itself, which means that $\mathbb{R}^2$ just as well isn't in the picture, and none of our answers should depend on how the cardioid is embedded in $\mathbb{R}^2$. (Yes, that's where we get our metric, but we could have just as well declared we were putting the given metric on the cardioid without any reference to where it came from.) So, in this setting we have a $1$-manifold, thus one-dimensional tangent spaces, and hence just one Christoffel symbol, $\Gamma_{11}^1$.

Comment: "What happens at the singularity?" is a tricky question. The cardioid $C$ does *not* inherit a smooth structure via its embedding in $\mathbb{R}^2$, precisely because it does have a singularity. On the other hand, $C$ is homeomorphic to a circle, which does have a canonical smooth structure, and by pulling it back via any homeomorphism, we get a smooth structure on $C$ itself, though in this case we may as well just be doing parallel transport on a circle. Anyway, with this smooth structure, $C \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ still isn't smooth!

Comment: There are other choices, for example, regarding $C$ as the image of an immersion of a half-open interval $[a, b)$ into $\mathbb{R}$, but this doesn't "see" the singularity, and this immersion is not an embedding, so the topology induced by regarding the immersion as a homeomorphism on $C$ is *not* the same as the subspace topology induced by $\mathbb{R}^2$. There are some further options yet that "see" the singularity, since things only go awry at a single point (and one of them, interestingly gives the "opposite" rule for what happens when we identify $C$ with a circle) but these are...

Comment: ...neither easy nor the most natural thing to do. In short, this is probably not a good example for understanding parallel transport.

Comment: @Travis has it nailed. My extended answer below details some of the same points.

Answer (score 2):

Parallel transport on a manifold $M$, along a curve $\gamma$ in $M$, is defined only for tangent vectors to $M$ that happen to lie at a point of the image of $M$. So if $M$ is the unit sphere, and $\gamma$ is a path going around the equator, then you can take any tangent vector at the equator and translate it along $\gamma$. But you can't take a tangent vector at, say, 34 degrees north latitude and translate it along the curve.

In your case, the manifold $M$ is the cardioid (as you said in the comments); presumably it inherits its metric from the ambient space (the plane). The path $\gamma$ is also the cardioid.

Before I get into details, let me observe that the cardioid --- the image of the $xy$-curve that you've written down --- is not actually a manifold. At the point described by $t = \pi$, the curve has a singularity, and the image of the tangent space to $\mathbb R$ at the point $t = \pi$ is carried, by the differential of $\gamma$ at $\pi$, $dg(\pi)$, to the zero vector in $\mathbb R^2$; one cannot therefore at that point inherit the metric from $\mathbb R^2$. (If you chase the definitions carefully, the inner product of any two vectors in $d\gamma(\pi)(\mathbf{T}\mathbb R_\pi)$ turns out to be zero, so every vector ends up having length zero, which isn't allowed in a metric on what should be a 1-dimensional vector space (the tangent space to our purported 1-manifold at $\gamma(\pi)$).

The next thing to observe is that because this (aside from the bad point) is a 1-manifold, the metric at any point $\gamma(t)$ is represented by a $1 \times 1$ matrix with a single entry, $g_{11}(t)$. That's gotten by taking the standard basis for the tangent space to $\mathbb R$ at the point $t$, namely the vector $[1]$, and pushing it forward through $d\gamma(t)$ to get a vector $A(t)$ in $\mathbb R^2$, and then computing the dot product (in $\mathbb R^2$) of that vector with itself. Let's do that.

And to simplify, I'm gonna get rid of the constant factor $a$ throughout.

We have:
$$
x(t)=(1+2\cos t + \cos 2t)\\
y(t)=(2\sin t + \sin 2t)
$$
so
$$
x'(t) = (-2 \sin t - 2 \sin 2t) \\
y'(t) = (2 \cos t + 2 \cos 2t).
$$

\begin{align}
A(t) &= d\gamma(t)([1]) \\
&= \begin{bmatrix}
-2 \sin t - 2 \sin 2t \\ 2 \cos t + 2 \cos 2t
\end{bmatrix}
[1] \\
&= \begin{bmatrix}
-2 \sin t - 2 \sin 2t \\ 2 \cos t + 2 \cos 2t
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}
So 
\begin{align}
g_{11}(t) = A(t)\cdot A(t)  &= 
&= (s \sin t + 2 \sin 2t)^2 + (2 \cos t + 2 \cos 2t)^2.
\end{align}

Now we can translate a particular tangent vector $X$ along this curve by writing out the transport equation. Let's, as an example, choose the vector 
$$
X = \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}
$$
at the point $\gamma(0) = (4, 0)$.

You're hoping to find a function $X: image(\gamma) \to \mathbb R^2$ with the properties that

1. $X(t)$ is a vector tangent to $M = image(\gamma)$ at $\gamma(t)$.
2. $X(0)$ is the vector $X$ that I wrote down above.
3. $X(t)$ satisfies the equation you wrote down involving the Christoffel symbols.

It may be easiest to say that $X(t) = (a(t), b(t))$, or $X(t) = (X_1(t), X_2(t))$, so that you have an explicit name for the coordinates of $X$.

At this point, it'd be good for you to write down those Christoffel symbols. How many are there? What are their values? What are the resulting equations?

My guess is that after reading this far, you're going to say "No, that isn't the question I was asking at all!", which is why I'm not writing out anything else just yet.

If it really is the question you want answered, by all means do some writing, and I'll continue my answer.

Comment: Hi,I agree this was not the answer to my question. But it's my fault. I tried to think of an example which I could calculate myself, but I failed in every sense. The question was not so much about the cardioid, but more about a concrete and calculated example. Next time, I just look for an exercise in a book or pdf and ask it here. At least we now know that the cardioid is a bad example. Thank you (and Travis) for your answer anyway :)